# MS SQL Database to SAS

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis, sas

Is there a way to extract data from MS SQL Server to SAS data set using SSIS? or using python? Is this possible?

I need simple transformation of data, SAS output not as datasource.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install SAS OLEDB provider and use OLEDB Destination to connect to SAS:

- [SAS Providers for OLE DB](https://support.sas.com/downloads/browse.htm?fil=&cat=64)

Or you must use a third party component such as CROZYROC SAS components:

- [COZYROC SAS](http://cozyroc.com/ssis/sas)
- [SAS SSIS integration components - Cozyroc SSIS Library](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=COZYROC.sascomponents)

Comment: Thanks! Will check this!